# Unable to execute the TestRunner File using Junit Cucumber Getting Incompatible Class Error

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, gherkin, feature-file

When I am running the Test Runner file I am getting Incompatible Class Error:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions does not implement the requested interface io.cucumber.core.options.FeatureOptions
>       at cucumber.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.get(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:23)
>       at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.(Cucumber.java:89)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>       at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)

Comment: Below is my pom.xml

Comment: Its very broad, where is your test ?

Comment: Add the pom to the question

Comment: Ensure you are using the same version of all `cucumber-` dependencies and run `mvn clean`.